# Printout results in while loop output different results in Java azure

Tags: java, php, azure

I am sending json object to azure cloud in java successfully.but the problem is my reciever,the message is recieved well but the problem is when i want to send it back to PHP:
I am sending this message:

> {"Id":"914897","Name":"Broken window","Description":"Window
>   broken","PriorityId":"1"}

As I receive this message I want to first printout the message to verify whether i am getting the results and i sent it.however inside the while loop is printing correct but outside a broken results here is my Code:

```
 try {

        Configuration config
                = ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithSASAuthentication(

                );


        ServiceBusContract service = ServiceBusService.create(config);

        ReceiveMessageOptions opts = ReceiveMessageOptions.DEFAULT;
        opts.setReceiveMode(ReceiveMode.PEEK_LOCK);
        //send object
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        Gson gson= new Gson();
        while (true) {
            ReceiveQueueMessageResult resultQM = service.receiveQueueMessage("mobile",opts);
            BrokeredMessage message = resultQM.getValue();
            if (message != null && message.getMessageId() != null) {
                System.out.println("MessageID: " + message.getMessageId());
                // Display the queue message.
                System.out.print("From queue:");
                byte[] b = new byte[20000000];
                String message_from_queue = null;
                String thu =null;
                String jsonn = null;
                int numRead = message.getBody().read(b);


                while (-1 != numRead) {
                    message_from_queue = new String(b);

                   message_from_queue  = message_from_queue .trim();                      
                   numRead = message.getBody().read(b);
                //System.out.print("inside while" +message_from_queue + **"\n");//{"Id":"914897","Name":"Broken window","Description":"Window broken","PriorityId":"1"}**


                                 try {


    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:3308/emlive/index.php/Api/createDefect");
    StringEntity params =new StringEntity("defect=" + message_from_queue );
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
    request.setEntity(params);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    //System.out.printf("---------------------------------Done-------------------------------");
    // handle response here...
    message.setSessionId("");
    System.out.println(org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
   org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    // handle exception here
} finally {
    httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
  }
                  //System.out.print("outside while" +message_from_queue +                   "\n");//Broken window","Description":"Window broken","PriorityId":"1"}                                                            

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Custom Property: "
                        + message.getProperty("MyProperty"));
                //service.deleteMessage(message);
                System.out.println("Deleting this message.");

                //service.deleteMessage(message);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Finishing up - no more messages.");
                break;
                // Added to handle no more messages.
                // Could instead wait for more messages to be added.
            }

        }
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        System.out.print("ServiceException encountered: ");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("Generic exception encountered: ");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

I am getting this results : Printing inside while loop:

```
 while (-1 != numRead) {
 message_from_queue = new String(b);

  message_from_queue  = message_from_queue .trim();                      
  numRead = message.getBody().read(b);

 System.out.print("inside while" +message_from_queue + **"\n");//{"Id":"914897","Name":"Broken window","Description":"Window broken","PriorityId":"1"}**
}
```

Printing outside while loop:

```
System.out.print("outside while" +message_from_queue + "\n");/*Broken window","Description":"Window broken","PriorityId":"1"}
```

Comment: Please explain why need to use inside while loop to send messages. I think the inside while loop is not necessary for send message thru http.

Comment: I removed the while loop but nothing is helping because i still get the broken results like this :                                         {"Id":"914451","Name":"Brok                                                                    This time is giving me the first broken string.

Answer (score 0):

All Thanks to Dominic Betts from this link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues/#comments

I used the following code to achieve my goal:

```
 StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 stringBuilder.append(message_from_queue );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was caused by doing the POST request in the inside while loop. Codes in the inside while loop is for reading messages from queue, So the POST request of HttpClient should be in the outside while loop.

I refered to the doc https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues/ and  modified your code as below:

```
try {
    Configuration config = ServiceBusConfiguration.configureWithSASAuthentication("<namespace>", "<sas_key_name>",
            "<sas_key>", ".servicebus.windows.net");
    ServiceBusContract service = ServiceBusService.create(config);
    ReceiveMessageOptions opts = ReceiveMessageOptions.DEFAULT;
    opts.setReceiveMode(ReceiveMode.PEEK_LOCK);
    // send object
    // HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    // Gson gson = new Gson();
    while (true) {
        ReceiveQueueMessageResult resultQM = service.receiveQueueMessage("mobile", opts);
        BrokeredMessage message = resultQM.getValue();
        if (message != null && message.getMessageId() != null) {
            System.out.println("MessageID: " + message.getMessageId());
            // Display the queue message.
            System.out.print("From queue:");
            byte[] b = new byte[20000000];
            String message_from_queue = null;
            // String thu = null;
            // String jsonn = null;
            int numRead = message.getBody().read(b);
            while (-1 != numRead) {
                message_from_queue = new String(b);
                message_from_queue = message_from_queue.trim();
                numRead = message.getBody().read(b);
                // System.out.print("inside while" +message_from_queue +
                // **"\n");//{"Id":"914897","Name":"Broken
                // window","Description":"Window
                // broken","PriorityId":"1"}**
            }
            // System.out.print("outside while" +message_from_queue +
            // "\n");//Broken window","Description":"Window
            // broken","PriorityId":"1"}
            int statusCode = -1;
            try {
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost:3308/emlive/index.php/Api/createDefect");
                StringEntity params = new StringEntity("defect=" + message_from_queue);
                request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                request.setEntity(params);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
                // System.out.printf("---------------------------------Done-------------------------------");
                // handle response here...
                message.setSessionId("");
                System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
                EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // handle exception here
            } finally {
                httpClient.close();
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Custom Property: " + message.getProperty("MyProperty"));
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Remove message from queue.
                System.out.println("Deleting this message.");
                service.deleteMessage(message);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Finishing up - no more messages.");
            break;
            // Added to handle no more messages.
            // Could instead wait for more messages to be added.
        }

    }
} catch (ServiceException e) {
    System.out.print("ServiceException encountered: ");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    System.exit(-1);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.print("Generic exception encountered: ");
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

Best Regards